# How do I include scattering in the Optical Transfer Matrix Method?

Tags: optics, scattering

I am using the Transfer Matrix Method (TMM) to model a system I have. Due to the size of my system effects such as Mie and Rayleigh scattering should be important.

How do I include Mie and Rayleigh scattering into a TMM model?